# How to install Splash on Windows Home?

Tags: windows, docker, splash-js-render

The [installation instructions](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) and all articles I have found talk about installing through Docker.

However, Windows Home does not support Docker, only Windows Pro does.

How can I install Splash on Windows Home?

Comment: [It seems possible to use Docker on Windows Home](https://www.sitepoint.com/docker-windows-10-home/), it’s just not as straightforward as it is with Windows Pro.

Comment: thanks @Gallaecio, appreciated.